# stuck on logic and propositional calculus problem

Tags: propositional-calculus

1.Show that  $\neg((\neg p\land q)\lor(\neg p\land \neg q))\lor(p\land q)\equiv p.$

$\neg((\neg p\land q)\lor(\neg p\land \neg q))\lor(p\land q)\equiv \neg(\neg p\land ( q\lor \neg q))\lor (p\land q)\equiv \neg(\neg p\land q)\lor (p\land q)\equiv (p\lor \neg q)\lor (p\land q).$

I stuck here.
I am very beginner in logics and propositional calculus.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $q\lor \neg q$ must be true, $\neg p\land (q\lor\neg q)\iff \neg p$ and therefore the proposition is equivalent to $p\lor (p\land q)$, which is thus equivalent to $p$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Thanks Sir!